# For $f(x) = e^x + x^3 - x^2 + x$ find the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{f^{-1}(x)}{\ln x}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, inverse-function

I have the function:

$$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{2cm} f(x) = e^x + x^3 -x^2 + x$$

and I have to find the limit:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f^{-1}(x)}{\ln x}$$

(In the first part of the problem, I had to show that the function is strictly increasing and invertible. I don't know if that's relevant to this, since I could show that the function is invertible, but I can't find the inverse.)

So this is what I tried:

I showed

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$$

and so I concluded that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f^{-1}(x) = \infty$. I'm not sure if this is correct, it might be wrong. But if would be right, then we could use l'Hospital, knowing that:

$$(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$

but after trying to use all of this on paper, I got nowhere. It just complicated thing a lot more.

So how should I solve this limit?

Comment: Why don't you just substitute $x=f(t) $ to get $t/\log f(t) $. This clearly tends to...

Comment: Your approach starts correctly but then wanders off due to strong attraction of L'Hospital's Rule. Here this is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : $$\forall x\geq 1\quad 2e^x \geq e^x+x^3-x^2+x\geq e^x+1$$

So $$\ln(\frac{x}{2})\leq f^{-1}(x)\leq \ln(x-1)$$

So we deduce that your limit is a constant by the sandwich theorem .

Comment: You also deduce what that number is...

Comment: @Ian yes it is one .

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is monotone increasing for $x$ large (for all $x$ even), we can substitute $f(y)$ for $x$ in the limit as follows.
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f^{-1}(x)}{\ln(x)} = \lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y}{\ln(f(y))}
$$
Now,

\begin{align}
\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y}{ln(f(y))} &= \lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y}{\ln(e^y + y^3 - y^2 + y)} \\
&=\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y}{y + \ln(1 + e^{-y}y^3 - e^{-y}y^2 + e^{-y}y)}. \\
\end{align}

As $e^{-y}$ times any polynomial goes to $0$ as $y \to \infty$ we see that the limit is $1$.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so late, but can you please explain how did you get that last line, from $\lim\limits_{y\to \infty} \frac{y}{\ln(e^y+y^3-y^2+y)}$ to $\lim\limits_{y \to \infty} \frac{y}{y+\ln(1+e^{-y}y^3 - e^{-y}y^2 + e^{-y}y)}$. That's the only thing I didn't understand in your approach.

Comment: @user1502  factor $e^y$ out from inside the logarithm (so $(e^y + y^3 - y^2 + y) = e^y(1 + e^{-y}y^3 - e^{-y}y^2 + e^{-y}y)$, then use $\ln(ab) = \ln(a) + \ln(b)$ and finally $\ln(e^y) = y$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my comment into an answer.

---

The derivative $$f'(x) =e^x+\text{ a polynomial in } x$$ clearly tends to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty $ and hence is positive in some neighborhood of type $(a, \infty) $ and therefore $f$ is strictly increasing in that neighborhood. This implies that $f$ is invertible in the same neighborhood.

Further $f(x) \to\infty $ as $x\to\infty $ hence $t=f^{-1}(x)$ also tends to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty $. Putting $t=f^{-1}(x)$  the limit in question reduces to $$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t} {\log f(t)} $$ and clearly $$\log f(t) = \log (e^t+p(t)) =t+\log(1+p(t)e^{-t})$$ where $p(t) $ is some polynomial and therefore $p(t) e^{-t} \to 0$. It follows that $$\frac {t} {\log f(t)} =\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{\log(1+p(t)e^{-t})}{t}}\to\frac{1}{1+0}=1$$ as $t\to\infty $.

---

The question is specifically intended to check whether one is trying to figure out the inverse of $f$ in explicit manner or not. The limit evaluation does not really require the inverse of $f$ and the idea is to transform the limit in question to one dealing with the function $f$.

Answer (score -1):

For $x \to \infty, f(x) \sim e^x$ so $f^{-1}(x) \sim \ln(x)$. So the answer is $1$.

Comment: $f(x) \to\infty $ as $x\to\infty $. Similarly $f^{-1}(x)\to\infty $. I wonder how you get the limits as $e^x, \ln x$. Limit of something as $x\to a$ must be independent of $x$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh for $x \to \infty$, $e^x >>> x^3,x^2,x$. Is this not right?

Comment: Your comment is right but we don't express it by saying $f(x) \to e^x$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh You mean the notation is incorrect or the statement itself? If the latter, why isn't it true if the above comment is true?

Comment: The notation $f(x) \to e^x$ is meaningless and I have never seen it used anywhere in standard textbooks.

Comment: Anyway in case you are wondering, the downvote is not mine.

Comment: I understand what you mean with $f(x) \to e^x,$ but a better notation would be "$f(x) \sim e^x$ for big $x>0.$"

Comment: Use `\sim` to get $\sim$.

Comment: Edited thanks..

Comment: It's unclear to me how you go from $f(x)\sim e^x$ to $f^{-1}(x)\sim\ln x$. It's not in general true that if $f(x)\sim g(x)$, then $f^{-1}(x)\sim g^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: @Wojowu Oh I didn't know that. Do you have any counter example?

Comment: @user600016 We have $\ln x\sim 1+\ln x$, but the inverse functions are $e^x,e^{x-1}$ which aren't asymptotically equal. This might be true for functions growing superlinearly, possibly under some extra conditions, but it is definitely not immediate.

Comment: Don't take it otherwise, but the key thing in analysis is "never assume things unless proved". Unfortunately when dealing with calculus / analysis people assume many things which probably help in getting answer easily. In algebra one hardly assumes $\sqrt{a+b} =\sqrt{a} +\sqrt {b} $ and one should follow same level of strictness in calculus/analysis topics also.